# Lightning Components - Facets or components-within-components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Long-time reader, first time poster.

I'm completing the lightning components trailhead modules, and am a little confused about the difference between facets nested components.

From the demos, it feels like both are the practically the same thing.
You can put a component inside a component, and you can put a component with a facet inside a component. Both let you set attributes in the child from the parent, and I can't really tell the difference in behaviour, and when we shoudl use which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composition ("putting a component inside a component") is really just shorthand for:

```
<aura:set attribute="body">
Some body content here
</aura:set>
```

its just syntactic sugar for the most common use of facets. Under the covers they are just facets.

Comment: Never got around to approving this.  The more I've played with lightning, the more I've realised they are the same thing :)